# Wordpress cforms plugin CAPTCHA image not displaying

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, captcha

I'm using the cformsII form plugin for Wordpress. When debugging with firebug, I see that the following uri is not able to be navigated to (404 error):

```
.../wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php?ts=2&c1=4&c2=5&ac=abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789&i=i&w=115&h=25&c=000066&l=000066&f=font4.ttf&a1=-12&a2=12&f1=17&f2=19&b=1.gif
```

I have verified that wp-content (including subdirectories and files) has proper `777` permissions. Furthermore, I verified that I could navigate to `1.gif` without issue. Finally, I verified that the GD library is installed as well.

Comment: If your webhost can't serve - /wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php .. check to see if it's even there?

Comment: I can access cforms-captcha.php, but not the derived URI

Comment: from docs: there is also a debug option in cforms.php (top) that'll include some useful stats hidden in your html source which helps troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with a corrupted captcha script. Was able to replace to correct the issue. Thanks folks.